# phpMyAdmin - table names

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When you have a table called `sheep` and you would like to call it `c` what would be the correct way to do this in phpMyAdmin when writing the query

Comment: `SELECT sheep_atribute FROM sheep AS c;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your phpMyAdmin database where the table is stored and go to the "SQL" tab.
Then proceed with this command:

```
RENAME TABLE table_name TO new_table_name
```

Or when you don't need to rename the table permanently you can use the AS statement

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM    sheep AS c
```

Answer (score 0):

phpMyadmin is just an interface to access your database.

you can use mysql `ALIASING` to call it by different name or words for example

```
SELECT c.* FROM sheep c;
```

here `c` refers to table `sheep` so whenever you want to refer to `sheep` tables column you use the alias `c`.

Answer (score 0):

It is called `ALIAS`. The basic syntax is:

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM    Sheep AS c
```

And `AS` is *optional*.

Answer (score 0):

You can give alias name like below query

```
Select * from sheep c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.* FROM sheep c
```

This is The Answer